# Allow static Large array in Cuda

Tags: cuda

The Gpu I work is a Tesla C2075 with 6gb VRAM. And the OS is Ubuntu 64 bit with cuda toolkit 5.5.
What do I need to do to allow  global `__device__` static arrays bigger than 2gb ?
I couldn't find many related topics in Google or here in StackOverflow.

Comment: The CUDA framework appears to have a limit of 2GB for static `__device__` allocations.  Use dynamic allocation methods (e.g. `cudaMalloc`) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I frequently see programs that allocate (*dynamically at least*) more than 2GB of data. So theoretically allocating a `__device__` array statically should be possible. To try and solve this, here are my suggestions:

- Update the graphics driver to the latest version (the new driver supports large allocations - up to 6GB - on K20, it should support it on your card as well)
- Update your CUDA toolkit to 6.5 (this may not be necessary but maybe CUDA 6.5 will get along better with the latest driver)

If this does not work, **I would try allocating page-locked memory (pinned).** Check **[here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g9f93d9600f4504e0d637ceb43c91ebad.html)** for more info. After allocating it, to make it visible on the device you need to map it. This enables DMA transfer and might be an even faster solution. I saw this approach in programs that allocate up to 5GB of device memory - see **[here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/software/view.html?id=204)**.

Comment: You're saying that if I  write __device__ int x[1000000000]; (4gb) it's supposed to run normally ? Without any special flag in the compiler?

Comment: I'm on another pc with Windows 7 right now, and I can't allocate more than 2gb with cudaMallocHost either.

Comment: Check my revised post

Comment: Actually, I'm able to use a 900mb global scope __device__ array fine. I will try with cudaLimitMallocHeapSize tough, thanks for pointing out cudaDeviceSEtLimit.

Comment: The question is about the allocation of a `__device__` variable. Not a thread-local variable.  Unfortunately OP's question was unclear.  And page-locked memory refers to host memory, not device memory.  Yes, it may become device visible (if mapped) but that is even farther afield from what OP is asking about.